# Managed objects, why won't (^). compile?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, pointers, c++-cli

I recently had the need to look into controlling a serial port so I turned to .net for this. I thought, since I'm using visual studio, this would easy...i was wrong...

After figuring out what the "`^`" and "`gcnew`" ment, I stumbled upon the "`->`" which I still found out to mean "`(*).`" (not knowing this is due to my own ignorance).

The question is this:

If "`->`" is equivalent to "`(*).`"
And "`^`" is equivalent to "`*`"

Then why won't "`(^).`" compile while typing it in brings up the auto complete? Or am I missing something here ?

Comment: Thanks for the fixes...seem typing questions out on a mobile phone didnt work quite so well.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've done C++ programming before.  The SerialPort class is available in the C# language as well.  It gives you much less of a challenge with syntax.

Comment: Well, I actually kind of agree with you...I've done a lot of more theoretical stuff, a lot on the side of algorithms but next to nothing on the "practical"side of programming.

Answer (score 5):

The hat (`^`) and percent (`%`) in C++/CLI are analagous<sup>(1)</sup> to the asterisk (`*`) and ampersand (`&`) in C++ *in types*.

The `^` is not used as an operator, though; you still use `*`.

---

(1) Note that they are not *the same* or *equivalent*.  `^` and `%` are used for handles and references to objects on the garbage collected heap (i.e., managed objects).  `*` and `&` are used for pointers and references to native C++ objects (at least for the most part).

You'll want to be very careful when programming in C++/CLI:  never forget that you have two completely different object models being used in a single source file.  The way that objects are created and destroyed and how object lifetimes are managed in C++ are completely different from how things work in .NET.

Comment: Right, but why on earth does "(^)." bring up the auto complete (suggesting that the syntax is correct or at least recognized)  yet give errors when compiling?

Comment: I have no idea; I don't have Visual Studio 2008 installed and Visual Studio 2010 does not support IntelliSense for C++/CLI at all.  Sorry.

Comment: "*When you need the operators, you still need to use `*` and `&`.*" Not entirely correct -- `%` is needed to get a handle to a managed object allocated with stack semantics, or to box a value object, or to get a handle from a tracking reference, etc.; unary `&` wouldn't compile in these scenarios. In fact, just about the only thing unary `&` is needed for regarding managed types is to take the address of a member function for use in creating delegate instances; `%` is used everywhere else I can think of unary `&` would be used in C++.

Comment: @ildjarn:  Well, that's what I get for answering questions way out of my realm of expertise.  Thanks for the correction.  [Also, you should join us at our next Seattle Stack Overflow meetup, whenever we have it.]

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk `*` is more general than the hat `^`. As a type modifier, `T*` means C++-pointer, and `T^` means CLI-reference. However, the other use of the symbol for the **dereference operator** applies to both types, and the indirect-call operator `->` does likewise:

```
T * x = new T;
T ^ y = gcnew T;

*x = 5;
*y = 6;

x->foo();
y->foo();
```

The idea is that dereferencing is a general concept that's independent of the particular type of reference, so the same symbol can be used to minimize syntax proliferation.

Answer (score 0):

if your only reason for using .net is to use a serial port, don't.  The native api is both more powerful and easier to use.